# image magick image cropping adds white space

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am using image magic to make a plugin for a CMS which can crop an image.

what I want to do is a to write a function, which takes an image, and resize it first, and then crop it to gererate a thumb which can show the maximum possible area of the image

so i have a test run here. I am trying to crop this image

http://dev.silverstripers.com/imagic/assets/Uploads/blog-dylan.gif

and i am cropping it with this command. (auto generated by my plugin )

```
convert [PATH_TO_HERE]/Uploads/blog-dylan.gif -resize 48%x48% -crop 100x100+54+0 -trim [PATH_TO_HERE]/Uploads/_resampled/someimage-blog-dylan.gif
```

but this is what it returns

http://dev.silverstripers.com/imagic/assets/Uploads/_resampled/someimage-blog-dylan.gif

my problem now is to get rid of that transparent area around the image which is added by image magick.

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well i found the Repage option

so i had to change my command like this

```
convert [PATH_TO_HERE]/Uploads/blog-dylan.gif -resize 48%x48% -crop 100x100+54+0 +repage[PATH_TO_HERE]/Uploads/_resampled/someimage-blog-dylan.gif
```

Comment: had the same issue with -append and +repage also worked for me